# Python optparse Values Instance

Tags: python, dictionary, optparse

How can I take the opt result of

```
opt, args = parser.parse_args()
```

and place it in a dict?  Python calls opt a "Values Instance" and I can't find any way to turn a Values Instance into a list or dict.   One can't copy items from opt in this way,

```
for i in opt:
 myDict[i] = opt[i]
```

instead, its a clumsy,

```
myDict[parm1] = opt.parm1
myDict[parm2] = opt.parm2
```

which implies that every time I add an option, I have to update this code as well; there should be a way to let this take care of itself.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
options, args = parser.parse_args()
option_dict = vars(options)
```

[(Source is this python-ideas post.)](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-March/003623.html)

Comment: Nice. I wasted 5 hours on that.

Comment: I have no clue how, after 12+ years of python, I didn't know about `vars()`. You learn something new all the time.

Comment: @Doctor - 12 years ago we didnt have stackoverflow

Comment: 12 years and it's the first time I've ever really used `vars()`